# Rails is adding API fields from nowhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm creating a `RESTful` API using the `Rails API Mode`.
I'm using `devise` to handle the user creation and `simple_token_authentication` to handle the token generation and authorization.

Here is how I'm making the fetch request :

```
  async requestAccountCreation(data) {
    await fetch('http://localhost:3000/users', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: data
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
  }
```

When I `console.log()` the data from `requestAccountCreation(data)` this gives me a valid JSON string, so no problem with that. Here is what is sent to the `Rails` server :

```
{"firstname":"Tristan","lastname":"Vermeesch","username":"PlayBossWar","email":"titivermeesch2@gmail.com","address":"Rue Haute, 37 5550 Chairière","password":"jsoaod"}
```

Now here is the `Rails` part, first my `user.rb` :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  validates :firstname, presence: true
  validates :lastname, presence: true
  validates :username, presence: true
  validates :address, presence: true
  validates :idcard, presence: true
end
```

The extra fields are fields that I added to the already existing ones that `devise` generated for me, I migrated all the files.

This is the `route` I used :

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

As you can see I added a custom controller to handle the extra fields, here it is :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :username, :idcard, :address)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :current_password, :username, :idcard, :address)
  end
end
```

I got this from a StackOverflow post.

Now I have an error in the console, here it is :

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-07-11 12:24:42 +0200
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"firstname"=>"Tristan", "lastname"=>"Vermeesch", "username"=>"PlayBossWar", "email"=>"titivermeesch2@gmail.com", "address"=>"Rue Haute, 37 5550 Chairière", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "registration"=>{"firstname"=>"Tristan", "lastname"=>"Vermeesch", "username"=>"PlayBossWar", "email"=>"titivermeesch2@gmail.com", "address"=>"Rue Haute, 37 5550 Chairière", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Unpermitted parameter: :registration
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "titivermeesch2@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Completed 200 OK in 452ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)
```

So it says that there is an unpermitted parameter `:registration`.
The thing is, I don't know where this comes from, I don't pass it in in my front-end so it has to be devise, but I don't know why it's doing this.

After disabled the wrapper as suggested, here is my error now :

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-07-11 13:46:28 +0200
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"firstname"=>"Tristan", "lastname"=>"Vermeesch", "username"=>"PlayBossWar", "email"=>"titivermeesch25@gmail.com", "address"=>"Rue Haute, 37 5550 Chairière", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "titivermeesch25@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Completed 200 OK in 430ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 10.9ms)
```

Comment: This is the same type issue but like the opposite side. His values don't get saved, but I have too much parameters. It's a parameter that don't come from the front-end.

Comment: What does the `html` page has to do with this? The data sent to `ruby` don't include `:registration`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've turned on config.wrap_parameters in your initializer [check the file **config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb**] or [you] are calling wrap_parameters() in your controller...the parameters will be cloned and wrapped in the key according to your controller's name by default.

Have a look here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

calling **wrap_parameters false** in the specific controller or at application controller will also stop this behaviour on a controller specific level and throughout the application respectively.

Comment: Thanks for that, I fixed that by just deleting the content of that file but now I have this issue : (Look at the edit in the question)

Comment: I can't see any issue other that the rollback() transaction, which is being caused because you already have a user with same email in you database. Can you please be more specific about the issue?

Comment: I don't have that email in my database, that's what's confusing me.

Comment: Just use **User.new(user_permitted_params).save!**, and it'll tell you the reason of failure, or you can also use **object.errors.full_messages** to know the actual reason.

Comment: So I have to create `users_controller.rb` for this? Since `devise` is handling all the `User` creation?

Comment: and this log line of your's "User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "titivermeesch25@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]" it self says that **"A user with the same email exists". I saw one more mistake, In your model you have **idcard** field as mandatory field, but you are not sending it to the controller.

Comment: I just figured that out (idcard). I created a user controller with the correct params and now it works. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Read content of `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`.

Then, either turn wrapping off (as described in comments of the file) OR permit parameters on key level like:

```
params
  .require(:registration)
  .permit(*%i[firstname lastname email password username idcard address])
```

[Extra info](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html).